AWS Cognito Exchange between Code and Access Token
After a successful authentication with the AWS Cognito Hosted UI, I am redirected to my callback url, example:
https://app.example.com/?code=16036818-2t63-4a31-98b0-e3c21aa9a24d

Using the Curl, I am able to obtain the Access Token using this request:
curl --location --request POST 'https://my-app.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=47akl6j7j4grj2js419' \
--data-urlencode 'code=16036818-2t63-4a31-98b0-e3c21aa9a24d' \
--data-urlencode 'redirect_uri=https://app.example'

However, if I run the CURL again, it gives me this error message:
{
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}

**Question: Does this exchange only happens once? **
I was expecting to get the same result.

This is probably to prevent replay attacks, the code is only valid once.

Thanks, so web applications like (VueJS) should receive the code, exchange to Access Token and use it instead?

Yes, that is the entire point of the code flow.
